# Issue with Customer validator in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a Custom Validator, which works as Server side and client side both.

It is working fine with one model, but when I am putting in to some other model, it’s giving me below error:

“0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference”.

I am not able to figure it out.

I have google this error ,but they suggested me to install or upgrade jquery validation  from Nuget.

But if in the same project it’s working for one model, so there won’t be an issue related to version.
Please suggest.

Comment: I bet your model is passing some null value to the validator which is not being able to handle it. However, why don't you show us your code so it's easier for us to seek a solution to your problem?

Comment: 1) Please provide some code. .2) The error is pretty clear, you're trying to access the `call` property of a `null` or `undefined` object.